# Find a precise field inside an object with an random key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Imagine this structure:

```
[...]
"items": {
    "UUID1": { "fieldIwant": [...] },
    "UUID2": { "fieldIwant": [...] },
    "UUID3": { "fieldIwant": [...] },
    "UUID4": { "fieldIwant": [...] },
    [...]
}
```

I have multiple documents with a similar structure and I need to filter by a value inside all of the uuids (for each document, so imagine i want all docs that has at least one `fieldIWant` equals to 5), I tried to use an aggregation with an `$objectToArray` which works but is really slow and knowing my prod will have x10 more docs than my local db I am a bit scared of the perfs this approach has.

I've did some researches on indexes but haven't found a way to use them to fit this precise use case.

What would be the ideal way to filter out what I want ? (I use PyMongo)

Comment: Have you checked out [wildcard index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/indexes/index-types/index-wildcard/reference/embedded-object-behavior/#wildcard-indexes-on-embedded-objects)?

Comment: I did yea but it seems like you still require the UUID to search no unless i'm mistaken by the doc

Comment: I would suggest refactoring the schema to something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i9XplzhnWcS) if possible. Using dynamic value as field name introduces unnecessary complexity to queries

Comment: That's sadly not possible to do

Comment: As written I think you've answered your own question. When you add the additional constraint regarding performance then I think you're at an impasse. Namely there is no way to run such a query on that schema in an efficient and scalable manner, not as far as I know at least