# mongo shell query of embedded documewnt

Tags: mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a collection built with embedded documents

```
{
    "actions" : {
            "2089233" : [
                    {
                            "task_name" : "Task1",
                            "params" : "abc"
                    }
            ],
            "2081111" : [
                    {
                            "task_name" : "c",
                            "params" : null
                    }
            ]
    },

}
```

I am trying to build query to count the number of documents that have at least one **params= "abc"**

my difficulty is that the elements under "Actions" can be any number. so i **cant** look for specific values (such as "2089233"),

appreciate any ideas how query this ?

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/76955378, which has a similar situation to you. Consider refactoring your schema if possible. Otherwise, you need to stick with `$objectToArray` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iloVQVkYlky); which may suffer from performance issue and unnecessary complexity

Comment: Can you give examples of what kind of lookup you want to do? So that we can help you better!?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti  
I am looking to count the number of documents (document like in the example) that have :   "task_name" : "Task1"  (anywhere under "Actions")